# Unable to use IN operator in DynamoDb Query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

The problem is I am getting error (Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: name).
tenant is my Primary Partition Key and name is my Primary Sort Key.

I need to write something equivalent to this in dynamo db: 
 Select * from projects where tenant = 'testProject' and name in ('John','Dave').

```
query = {
    TableName: 'projects',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#tenant': 'tenant',
        '#name' : 'name'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":tenant": 'testProject',
        ":user1" : "John",
        ":user2" : "Dave"
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: '#tenant = :tenant',
    FilterExpression: '#name IN (:user1,:user2)'
};
```

Comment: Is this a copy of the code used? I see you have backticks on projects in TableName. Is this correct?

Comment: I have corrected it. Now it is the copy of the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

As of the day that I am writing this, you cannot use `IN` in your key condition expression, nor can you include a key attribute in your filter expression.

The way to do what you’re wanting to do is with a [`BatchGetItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) request, which allows you to specify the full primary key for multiple items.